# Strip microsecond from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

For a given timedata - `2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00`, I want to remove microsecond and strip the value after '+'. Most of my dataset contains values like `2018-06-04 11:30:00+00:00` without the microsecond part.

How to have a common date time format for all values?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the datatype of time data? Is it a string/ datetime?? And where are you stuck at?

Comment: The data type is in the string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering your question with an assumption that the **type of the data is a string**.

If you are facing problem in handling in different formats like `"2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00"` and `"2018-06-04 11:30:00+00:00"` you can use `split()`.
Learn more about `split()` at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)

```
str_data_time.split("+")[0].split(".")[0]
```

#### Like,

```
for str_data_time in ["2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00", "2018-06-04 11:30:00+00:00"]:
    output = str_data_time.split("+")[0].split(".")[0]
    print(output)
```

The output of the above script is,

```
2018-06-01 06:36:40
2018-06-04 11:30:00
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the index [0] near split. Sorry, I am new to this language and in the learning process

Comment: When you split a string, it splits into 2 parts. [0] corresponds to the first half of the split while [1] corresponds to the second half of the split.

Comment: Your assumption was solid, and nailed my use-case. A great example of the legendary Open Source community. Definitely warrants the accepted answer. Thanks for saving me time.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a mix of different formats that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = ['2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00', '2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00', '2018-06-04 11:30:00+00:00', '2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883']
```

Corresponding output:

```
                               time
0  2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00
1  2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883+00:00
2         2018-06-04 11:30:00+00:00
3        2018-06-01 06:36:40.047883
```

You wish to get to a common format by removing microseconds and anything after +. In short, you want something that is in Y-M-D H-M-S format.

Currently, let me assume that your column is in string format. So, we now convert this to a datetime format and then replace the microseconds part with 0 and get rid of it.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond = 0))
```

Output:

```
                 time
0 2018-06-01 06:36:40
1 2018-06-01 06:36:40
2 2018-06-04 11:30:00
3 2018-06-01 06:36:40
```

Comment: Very nice solution using `Pandas` - Can be used for a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve that is by using str.split:

```
t = "2018-06-04 11:30:00+00:00"
t.split('+')[0]
```